# Information about a process in Linux (c)

Tags: c, process, operating-system, fork

If I use the fork() function to create a new process, is there any tools or functions that indicates how many time passed since it was created ? 

 than you

Comment: No, you will have to write it your own timer by using the provided syscalls.

Comment: Is there any examples/hints about this ?

Comment: "man -k timer" is a start.

Comment: Do you want to profile the `fork` system call?